# How to get console output into a txt file (using python flask server)

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Let's suppose I have a server code and when the function savePersonList() is called, the result printed on console should be saved into a text file.

```
#server coding

app = Flask(__name__)
def allowed_file(filename):
  # this has changed from the original example because the original did not work for me
    return filename[-3:].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST']) #integrate code below function
def upload_file(): 

    if request.authorization and request.authorization.username == 'user1' and request.authorization.password == 'pass2': #login code line
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print("This is a post Request \n\n")
            file = request.files['file']
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                print("File Sent is valid \n\n")
                print('**found file', file.filename)
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename) #use this from existing code before calling video capture 
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))  
    #code
                ''' This is the start of face recongition script '''
                CF.Key.set('d7c5495c64a44bc692761cd7c45ad56e')
                CF.BaseUrl.set('https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/')

                firstRun = True
                lastRun  = False

                #savePersonList()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are running on linux just use `python app.py > file.txt`(provided file.txt is created) might as well work on windows.

and add logger to your flask app as described in [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/logging/)

so you can write it for each request yourself
the file.txt then acts as your debug log.Hope it helps.

Comment: with this I'm getting only this output:afshan@afshan-VirtualBox:~/Microsoft_Azure/phase_2/flalsk_azure$ python3 video_json.py > output.txt
 * Running on http://192.168.0.112:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 255-995-400

Answer (score 5):

The answer of srinath samala is correct is the general case, but as you mentionned on the comment, not all the output is redirected to the file.

---

This is because some output of your Flask app is redirected to STDERR, and not only STDOUT.

To redirect both into your txt file, you want to use this :

`python app.py >> file.txt 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect sys.stdout to be a file (see [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4675728/5583602)) but it might be better to use the logging module.